# Extract multiple column headers into a vertical list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a sheet set up like this:

[image]

(this is a simplified view; the actual sheet is dynamic in both dimensions)

And I want to retrieve the top cells where they are ticked below, and to put them as a vertical list, like this:

[image]

I figured I could use INDEX or MATCH, maybe as an array, however I'm not sure how to go about this in order to put it neatly as a list.

Comment: Use [TRANSPOSE() function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/transpose-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027)

Answer (score 0):

It is more likely that your "real" problem will be solved by using TRANSPOSE and a filter.

But for you immediate question, you can use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(NAME,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(VAL="x")*COLUMN(VAL),ROWS($1:1))-1),"")
```

[image]